# Trouble with simple Python Code

Tags: python

I'm learning Python, and I'm having trouble with this simple piece of code:

```
a = raw_input('Enter a number: ')

if a > 0:
    print 'Positive'
elif a == 0:
    print 'Null'
elif a < 0:
    print 'Negative'
```

It works great, apart from the fact that it always prints 'Positive', no matter if i enter a positive or negative number or zero. I'm guessing there's a simple solution, but i can't find it ;-)

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Because you are using `raw_input` you are getting the value as a String, which is always considered greater than 0 (even if the String is '-10')

Instead, try using `input('Enter a number: ') and python will do the type conversion for you.`

The final code would look like this:

```
a = input('Enter a number: ')
if a > 0:
    print 'Positive'
elif a == 0:
    print 'Null'
elif a < 0:
    print 'Negative'
```

However, as a number of folks have pointed out, using input() may lead to an error because it actually interprets the python objects passed in.

A safer way to handle this can be to cast raw_input with the desired type, as in:

```
a = int( raw_input('Enter a number: '))
```

But beware, you will still need to do some error handling here to avoid trouble!

Comment: The reason input() works this way is because whatever is typed by the user is evaluated by the interpreter... which is very unsafe.  A search of the internet will provide numerous reasons why, but suffice it to say that doing int(raw_input()) within a try-catch should be considered better practice.

Comment: True, you can find discussion on this here: 
http://mail.python.org/pipermail/tutor/2003-January/019634.html

The initial example is useful for getting a person who is new to python going.  Once you start to consider error handling, you'll want to validate any and all user input, and at that point raw_input(...) will prove more useful.

Comment: Agreed.  The whole try-catch thing could be confusing to newbies.

Comment: using `input` is not safe.  Try using `a = int(raw_input('Enter:'))` instead

Answer (score 7):

That's because `a` is a string as inputted. Use `int()` to convert it to an integer before doing numeric comparisons.

```
a = int(raw_input('Enter a number: '))
if a > 0:
    print 'Positive'
elif a == 0:
    print 'Null'
elif a < 0:
    print 'Negative'
```

Alternatively, `input()` will do type conversion for you.

```
a = input('Enter a number: ')
```

Answer (score 7):

Expanding on my comment on the [accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1395603/trouble-with-simple-python-code/1395635#1395635), here's how I would do it.

```
value = None
getting_input = True

while getting_input:
    try:
        value = int(raw_input('Gimme a number: '))
        getting_input = False
    except ValueError:
        print "That's not a number... try again."

if value > 0:
    print 'Positive'
elif value < 0:
    print 'Negative'
else:
    print 'Null'
```

Comment: you dont' need getting_input here, you can just use 'while not value'. :P

Comment: While true, I prefer being fairly explicit in what goes on, so the intent of the code is obvious at a glance, without any additional thought.

Answer (score 5):

```
raw_input
```

returns a string so you need to convert `a` which is a string to an integer first: `a = int(a)`

Answer (score 2):

`raw_input` is stored as a string, not an integer.

Try using `a = int(a)` before performing comparisons.

Answer (score 1):

raw input will return a string, not an integer.  To convert it, try adding this line immediately after your raw_input statement:

a = int(a)

This will convert the string to an integer.  You can crash it by giving it non-numeric data, though, so be careful.